# Strange font behavior in "displaying source code mode" of Firefox

Tags: firefox, charset

When visiting "http://www.veritech.co.kr/" and displaying the source code (ctrl-u) the font used for the displaying the code is different from the usual font. The charset used by this page is not very usual (euc-kr) but why would it affect the way the *source code* is displayed ? What might be causing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is encoded in EUC-KR (Extended Unix Code - Korean) charset.

When you view source, Firefox will attempt to show the source code in the same charset as the rendered HTML.

You can see it in another encoding by changing at the following:

> View > Character Encoding

Answer (score 0):

The source code, specifically the title element, contains characters Firefox correctly detects to be in the Korean character set (see View -> Character Encoding in the source viewer), so it applies the font it needs, which is unlikely to be the default font, which has different-looking latin characters as well.